# how to get data-vale1, data-value2, data-value3 from a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get data-vale1, data-value2, data-value3 from a button

```js
$('.update').on('click', function() {

  var obj = $(this).data();
  var empId = $(this).data('logDate');
  var indexId = $(this).data("index");
  var logDate = $(this).data("logDate");
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(indexId);
  console.log(empId);
  console.log(logDate);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="update" data-empId="123" data-indexId="234" data-logDate='2020-01-01'>click </button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUlZM.png)

this is the result

```
{logdate: "2020-01-01", indexid: 234, empid: 123}
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve data- attributes via `.data`, the data attribute should be in kebab-case, eg `data-foo-bar`, *not* in `camelCase`. Then you can retrieve them by passing a `camelCase`d string into `.data`:

```js
$('.update').on('click', function() {

  var obj = $(this).data();
  var empId = $(this).data('empId');
  var indexId = $(this).data("indexId");
  var logDate = $(this).data("logDate");
  // console.log(obj.indexId);
  console.log(indexId);
  console.log(empId);
  console.log(logDate);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="update" data-emp-id="123" data-index-id="234" data-log-date='2020-01-01'>click </button>
```

That's the best way to do it, but if you can't change the HTML, you can also use `attr`:

```js
$('.update').on('click', function() {

  var obj = $(this).data();
  var empId = $(this).attr('data-empId');
  var indexId = $(this).attr('data-indexId');
  var logDate = $(this).attr('data-logDate');
  // console.log(obj.indexId);
  console.log(indexId);
  console.log(empId);
  console.log(logDate);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="update" data-empId="123" data-indexId="234" data-logDate='2020-01-01'>click </button>
```

Or, from the `.data()`, extract the attributes, but they'll have lost their casing:

```js
$('.update').on('click', function() {

  var obj = $(this).data();
  var empId = obj.empid;
  var indexId = obj.indexid;
  var logDate = obj.logdate
  // console.log(obj.indexId);
  console.log(indexId);
  console.log(empId);
  console.log(logDate);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="update" data-empId="123" data-indexId="234" data-logDate='2020-01-01'>click </button>
```

Comment: so its the camelCase. thanks this was such a noob question from me. sorry

Comment: It's an unintuitive behavior. jQuery, just like JS's `.dataset`, expects data attributes to be kebab-cased in the HTML, but to access them via JS you have to use camelCase.

Comment: thanks for the explanation too. its more clear now.